# Sinatra global application variable

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've got a simple Sinatra app that I'd like to share a variable across all sessions and requests.

```
configure do
  @@click_count = 0
end

def send_message(text)
  # ignore, this part works
end

post '/click' do
  @@click_count = @@click_count + 1
  send_message "clicks: #{@@click_count}"
end
```

**The message sent is always `clicks: 1` instead of incrementing.** I've also tried `set :click_count, 0` and then `settings.click_count = settings.click_count + 1` but I still get the same thing.

I'm running the server locally with shotgun using `shotgun web.rb -p 4567 -E production` because another question mentioned in non-production environments the server is restarted on each request which loses the state.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: And yes, I know this is a bad idea. It's a learning exercise, not a production app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sinatra itself doesn’t restart on each request in development mode ([it used to](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading)), but [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun) has that effect:

> Each time a request is received, it forks, loads the application in
>   the child process, processes the request, and exits the child process.

Simply use `ruby web.rb`, and everything should work (modulo threading issues that from you comment it looks like you’re aware of).

Comment: ruby web.rb worked. Is there a way to do this but still using shotgun? If not, it's cool it works locally and on Heroku, but I'd like to be able to test it locally still using shotgun.

Comment: I'm guessing you've already considered a key-value store as a possible option :)

Comment: @JohnSheehan Because shotgun is spawning a new process on each request, the variable is being reinitialized each time. You'd have to store it external to the process somehow, perhaps in a database of some sort. You could simply use a file, but that would be difficult on Heroku with their read-only filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how often the `configure` block gets run.  Try using a global variable (e.g. `$click_count`) instead of a class instance variable and initialize it at the very top of your program, outside of any block.